# "state information is invalid for this page" error

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an error comes up in aspx page:

The state information is invalid for this page and might be corrupted.

What would be the problem?

Comment: See: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/25f2886c-b560-434e-8dab-44a8adf4d34a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen once the ViewState is corrupted. Also is there ViewState Validation enabled i.e. EnableViewStateMAC=true in Page?

Answer (score 1):

I think this also happens if you post one page's viewstate to another page - you have to wire this up first or post back to the same page and redirect the request to the other page on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when you're rebuilding the control tree on postback and it's not exactly the same as the control tree when you were databinding/loading the page the first time (before postback).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I was killing myself. Apparently I had two `<form runat="server">...</form>`.
You are allowed to have two `<form>` tags but only one of them can have `runat="server"` attribute.